# Align Plotly axis text in R

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to left align the y-axis text in the following plot:

```
fig <- plot_ly(
  y = c("giraffes", " orange orangutans", "pigs"),
  x = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar", 
  orientation = 'h'
)
fig
```

When the text is uneven in length, I would prefer to have the text aligned to the left.

If possible, I would like a reference provided for what I can pass into the list for yaxis, too. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

from what I found here is no possibility to left align y-axis labels (https://community.plotly.com/t/left-align-category-labels-on-y-axis/3044)

a work arround would be to put the labels inside the bars or outside of them at the right side:

```
library(plotly)

fig %>% 
  plotly::layout(yaxis= list(showticklabels = FALSE)) %>% 
  plotly::style(text = c("giraffes", " orange orangutans", "pigs"), textposition = "auto", insidetextanchor="start")
```

[image]

You can find the reference for yaxis here: https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/yaxis/

Comment: Thank you! I have encountered this work around, but it does not render well for values with long names and small values.

Comment: you could also use string padding to fill the shorter values up with spaces at the end. But the lenght of letters is distinct so the result is not totally left alligned. So instead of only using y = c("giraffes", "orange orangutans", "pigs") you could try stringr::str_pad(c("giraffes", "orange orangutans", "pigs"), m_char, side = "right") where m_char <- max(nchar(c("giraffes", " orange orangutans", "pigs")))

Comment: the other option I see is to put the labels on the outer right side and increase the xaxis limit (in case something gets cut due to size)